# swift when should return have parenthesis and when does it not matter?

Tags: swift

Is there ever a case where "return n" will cause a problem due to something within ". . ." ?

```
func foo() -> Int
{
    . . .
    return n
}
```

Or, should I always use return( n ) ?

```
func foo() -> Int
{
    . . .
    return( n)
}
```

UPDATE...
The main reason for this question is trouble I once had in viewDidLoad() where the final instruction line was simply "return" because I didn't believe () were needed.  However, I had several lines below, which got executed.

(I had temporarily inserted the line with just "return" while debugging.)

This caused confusion and took a while to debug.

From then on, my policy was to always use return( . . . ) and never saw the problem again.

Someone on StackO explained this Swift behavior, but I don't remember the explanation.

Comment: In some languages it used to be a standard to put parentheses around boolean conditions, e.g. `return (a == 2)`.
However, there is never a reason  to randomly wrap variables in parentheses.

Comment: The only time you need the parentheses is when returning a tuple. Otherwise it is noise. If you're seeing code with lots of unnecessary parentheses, that often suggests that the author is new to Swift, having come from another programming languages where parentheses were required.

Comment: Doug you don't need to put `return` in void functions (like `viewDidLoad`) unless you want to do a early return out of some logic (but I doubt that's what you're going for here)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the parentheses are needed unless you declare your function to return a tuple.

As gnasher says in their answer, the parens in the return are weird.

I seem to remember that a function result in Swift is always considered to be a tuple, where `Void` is a special case empty tuple. If my (vague) memory is correct that might explain why the parens are valid. I need to see if I can dig that up.

Comment: 1-tuple doesn't exist in Swift for exactly the reason that it would create language conflicts.
Parens are valid because you can wrap any expression in parens.

Comment: I suspect the thing that Duncan is thinking of is situations where Void is an explicit type, for example in `Result<Void, Error>`. In that case, you pass `()` to mean Void. (i.e. `return .success(())`, yes double parens are required). In principle, `return ()` is valid in any case that you're returning Void (which is what functions that "don't return a value" actually return), but I'm not sure which way the compiler *actually* interprets this. Does it construct a Void and throw it away, or does it just skip that and throw it away? (But agreed with Sulthan in this case. `(1)` is just `1`.)

Comment: Without the parens, does Swift execute any lines that follow the "return"?  Sometimes it's convenient to temporarily insert a "premature" return from a func.  Is inserting "return()" the only way to do this?  It is the only way I, as a Swift newbie, know.

Comment: The parentheses do nothing. `return` and `return()` mean **exactly** the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are absolutely weird. They are weird in C, in Swift they are bizarre.

And since space is relevant in Swift, your weird spacing makes it even weirder.

As a rule, you don’t write anything unnecessary in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer to my question:

> Parens are only needed if line with "return" is between lines of code
> in same func.   Other than that case, as far as I know, parens after
> return are superfluous.

Here is my test for proving this............
With this code (no parens after return)...

```
print("viewDidLoad  Abort.")
return
print("viewDidLoad  WTF!")
```

...I get:

> viewDidLoad  Abort.
> viewDidLoad  WTF!

But, with this code (parens after return)...

```
print("viewDidLoad  Abort.")
return()
print("viewDidLoad  WTF!")
```

...I only get:

> viewDidLoad  Abort.

Thus, in response to all the esteemed advice above, I shall not use parens after return, unless temporarily aborting a func by using "return()" unless there is a better way to temporarily abort func.